# Firestone documents create dynamically with python script

Tags: python, firebase

I have a `.csv` file.

For example:

```
record-1a, record-1b, record-1c, document-name-1
record-2a, record-2b, record-2c, document-name-2
```

I would like to solve that after running my python script, it will create 2 document (depends on the number of the lines from the .csv) with the `document-name-N` names.

This is my code now:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore
from array import array
import csv

cred = credentials.Certificate('firebase-sdk.json')

with open('foo/bar/file.csv', 'r', newline='', encoding="utf8") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    data = []
    for row in reader:
        data.append(row)

firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db = firestore.client()

doc_ref = db.collection('collectionname').document(row[3])

for item in data:
    doc_ref.set({
        'someArray': [],
        'column1': item[0],
        'column2': item[1],
        'column3': item[2]
})
```

I've already checked this doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

but it didn't help me find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore
from array import array
import csv

cred = credentials.Certificate('firebase-sdk.json')

with open('foo/bar/file.csv', 'r', newline='', encoding="utf8") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    data = []

    firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
    db = firestore.client()

    for row in reader:
        print(row)
        data.append(row)

        content = ({
            'someArray': [],
            'column1': item[0],
            'column2': item[1],
            'column3': item[2]
        })
        db.collection('collectionname').document(row[5]).set(content)
```

I am a little beginner with the python so I barely know what was the problem.
If somebody can write some lines about the problem, I would be very glad.

Answer (score 2):

In the first code sample, you were using `doc_ref` inside the `for` loop, so I guess the result after running your script was that only one document was generated with the data from the last row of your json file. The actual behavior was that you immediately overwrote the document with each row of that file. In the second sample, you are creating a new reference for each row, so it is producing different documents for each of them.